# Finding the open circuit voltage

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, current-source, thevenin

I am asked to find the open circuit voltage v(AB).

So far, I have found the current, I(1) by using the current divider, and I got approximately: 0.307A.

Except, I am not sure where to go on from here to find the open circuit voltage.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.
 [image]

Comment: If you know the current through the 68 ohm resistor, don't you know the voltage across it?

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not even consider what I had calculated using the voltage divider. Very silly question, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Open circuit voltage is the voltage which is across 68 ohm resistor. Open circuit voltage is always the voltage of the component to whom the open circuit is parallel.

Comment: That works in this case, but sometimes there is not a convenient single component with which the open circuit voltage is in parallel.  In the more general case, the open circuit voltage is simply the voltage when there is no load.

Answer (score 2):

All you do is apply ohm's law to solve this.

first find the source voltage by finding the load resistance and multiply that by the known current.

so \$ \frac1{  \ \frac {1}{47}+\frac {1}{22+68} } \$= \$ \frac1{  \ \frac {1}{47}+\frac {1}{90} }  = 1/(0.0213 + 0.0111)= 1/0.0324= 30.876 \ \Omega \$

0.750 A * 30.876 ohms= 23.157 V

find the current in the 22 ohm and 68 ohm branch....
\$\frac{23.157\ V}{90\ \Omega} = 0.257\ A\$

now lets see what the voltage drop across the 68 ohm resistor....

0.257299269 * 68= 17.496350292 V

Comment: -1 and voting to delete.  Not only does this attempt to directly answer a homework question, but is absurdly deep into false precision, and it's wrong in addition.

Comment: 1. I don't know that this is a "Homework Question" @OlinLathrop 2. I guess I could round if that will make you happy. 3. Ohm's law hasn't changed, neither has kirchoff's law and its quite accurate.

Comment: but I will round it if you want.

Comment: your mad because I answered the question correctly. Now whether or not the stupid math notation got you biased. I don't care. Its stupid to have a electronics forum that that doesn't have the fractional notation options in the interface.

Comment: @drtechno It is correct, so I disagree with the deletion on that ground. Do you know LaTeX? You can wrap things with \$ at each end and write normal LaTeX in there. I've done one equation as an example. False precision, yes ;)

Comment: I don't know latex, but I'll look into it @awjlogan

Comment: "*Ohm's law hasn't changed, ...*". True, but a look at the resistor values shows that they are standard E12 series which typically are +/- 1 to 10%. In addition most will have some non-zero temperature coefficient. That's why 10 significant digits would not be used in a calculation by an experienced designer.

Comment: MathJAX fraction syntax is `\$ \frac {top}{bottom} \$` which gives \$ \frac {top}{bottom} \$. See [MathJAX basic turorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: to be honest i just use a calc. but I always learned to round at the end though... and even then for sizing parts you might round again to get the closest value

Comment: that latex is crazy language btw.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you @Transistor, but in high frequency and ac formulas, its just better to round at the end then accidentally cut of significant numbers in calculations. Here its not needed, and I'm just lazy that way...

Comment: @awj: No, this answer is also wrong.  Note the polarity of the current source and how Vab is defined. Maybe I should have also mentioned the incorrect units earlier.  The last line, for example, shows the product of two dimensionless numbers resulting in a value of Ohms.  Clearly that can't be right.

Comment: @drt: On a separate topic, was that you who downvoted 12 separate answers and questions of mine within a few minutes?  That's not how this site works.  I could have silently downvoted your answer, but I did you the service of explaining my objections. No, I'm not going to hunt down other posts of yours and downvote them, even if you admit to the revenge downvotes.  All your other posts are independent of this one, so that would make no sense and do the site a disservice.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to progressively simplify the circuit into either a single Thevenin or Norton source.

For example, if going the Thevenin route, combine the current source and the 47 Ω resistor to make the equivalent Thevenin source. Now combine that with the 22 Ω resistor to make the equivalent Thevenin source of everything left of the 68 Ω resistor. Now you have a simple problem of a Thevenin source with a resistive load. It is now simple to solve for the voltage across the 68 Ω resistor.

Comment: Would whoever downvoted this, would you care to explain what is wrong, or is this just a revenge downvote because of my downvote on the attempt to answer a homework question?

Comment: This is probably the best way to solve this, and it shows the steps to get to the solution too, without directly answering the homework question. So the downvote is incorrect.